# Setting a Value by assuming column in a Table MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a table with 8 column and following values
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
i need a query which will analyze the no of 1's and 0s in the column and if no of 0 is 
greater than 4 then it should print failed else pass,how can i do that? either by MYSQL or PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN `1`+`2`+`3`+`4`+`5`+`6`+`7`+`8` < 4 THEN 'Failed' ELSE 'Passed' END
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: this is also correct, but as Daniel Gave me the answer first, i will tick his answer as correct,but i will use your method in my program

Comment: Yes, that's a clever solution as well, assuming the columns store just ones and zeros. +1

Answer (score 1):

Might not be very neat, but you can count the number of 0s with a query such as the following (assuming your columns are named `1`, `2`, etc:

```
SELECT IF(`1` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`2` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`3` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`4` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`5` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`6` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`7` = 0, 1, 0) +
       IF(`8` = 0, 1, 0) NoOfZeros
FROM   your_table;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (`1` int, `2` int, `3` int, `4` int, 
                         `5` int, `6` int, `7` int, `8` int);

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0);
```

Result:

```
+-----------+
| NoOfZeros |
+-----------+
|         4 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can run this query from PHP, and display the error message you require when the `NoOfZeros` field in the result set is greater than 4.

Comment: thks this is the answer, i need to know one more thing,what did this means IF(`3` = 0, 1, 0)?

Comment: @Alex: That means: If column 3 is equal to 0, return 1, else return 0. Then we sum up all these return values. That's how we count the number of zeros.